# How to disable internal scrolling of a recyclerview but maintain outer list scrolling? (as shown in the material design guidelines)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-cardview

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
[Link to google's material design guide](https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#behavior)

[image: https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#behavior]

In my case I have multiple cards in a scrollView, which contains a linear layout. I did not use a recycler view because the number of cards is always about the same (below 10). One of the cards contains two recyclerviews showing a list of for example comments. The problem is that I can't find a way to disable scrolling of the internal recyclerview without causing it to not scroll at all and show incomplete data.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you use a RecyclerView if you don't need the content to scroll?

Comment: @Eselfar I want the content to scroll, but not in another window, see the material guide mentioned above

Comment: What do you mean 'in another window'? Do you use the same layout somewhere else?

Comment: @Eselfar Look at the two examples in the material guide, I had the one on the right working but did not know how to achieve the left one

Comment: Yeah this is what I was saying. Why do you use a RecyclerView if you don't want your content to scroll?

Comment: @Eselfar I use a recyclerview with the purpose of getting a better/smoother ui

Comment: Ok but the purpose of the Recycler is to have a list of scrollable items. As you don't want the scroll I don't see the advantage of using a Recycler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a NestedScrollView and put your RecyclerView inside it.

If you wish the RecyclerView to become a scrolling part of your NestedScrollView, set nested scrolling to false.

```
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.myNestedScrollView);
nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

If you want an independent scroll you don't need to do anything since nested scrolling is set to true by default.

Comment: How is rendered the RecyclerView in this configuration? Does it still recycle the views or display the entire content?

Comment: I can not test it at the moment to give you an accurate answer but i would say it does if the RecyclerView container fills the visible screen. This is easy to test on debug mode.